# how to change colour of action bar tabs on click for a few seconds only in android

Tags: android

I am using action bar tabs(not tabhost) . I want to change colour of my selected tab for a second (like whtsapp). I have used this code but its not working and this code is also hiding my tabs text.

```
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
{
   TextView v=new TextView(TabActivity.this);
   Log.d("TextView", v.toString());
   v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);  
   tab.setCustomView(v);
}
```

Comment: Whats that?? can you please provide some code snippet how to use it in android action bar tabs

Comment: https://github.com/Genng/RippleEffect_Android5.0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27565906/how-to-add-ripple-effect-on-android-action-bar-button-click-event

Comment: i think you want like this

Comment: Yes i want the same thing. But can you please provide some other example(a bit easier and clear) with respect to Action bar tabs